# How can I play a single tone or custom wave with Delphi?

Tags: windows, delphi, playsound

I looked up some code, seems like everything is creating some math function waves, but I want to a single tone, or a custom wave made with custom single tones.

I read this
[How can I generate continuous tones of varying frequencies?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742377/how-can-i-generate-continuous-tones-of-varying-frequencies)

Which is close to my answer.
Assumin I'm gonna use waveOutWrite like in the above link, I can't seem to figure out how the amp/freq is calculated for each Sample in HWAVEOUT.

In the code from the link It's done like this:
`Samples[i] := round(vol*sin(omega*t));`

Assuming I want a 15kHz freq single tone with some amp (does not matter which), how would a Sample[1] be calculated?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A continuous (in time) sine wave can be defined as `A*sin(2*PI*f*t)`, where `A` is some amplitude, `PI` is, well, 3.14..., `f` is the tone frequency in Hertz and `t` is time in seconds.

Now, since you don't have continuous time, since your time is discrete, you substitute `dt*i` in place of `t` and get `A*sin(2*PI*f*dt*i)`, where `dt` is the time between samples or `1/sample rate` and `i` is the sample number. You can spell it out as `A*sin(2*PI*(f/Fs)*i)`. Beware that once you choose a certain sample rate `Fs` (in samples/second or simply Hz), the highest tone can never be greater than `Fs/2` Hz.